# How to check exact style from two excel file using apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

I want to compare two excel file cell style. By using **apache poi** how can i compare styles cell by cell?
And also i need which style is not matched, like align or bold or color..etc. That means unmatched styles should be a string(style name - align, color....)

Comment: Got one solution. Please check!

Answer (score 1):

With [Cell.getCellStyle()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellStyle%28%29) you can find out the style per cell. With that you can check the fine granular [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) settings.

Comment: Already i tried this. But it's not much enough for my question. It returns only the style object. But i want style property (like alignment,color ...etc)

Answer (score 1):

You might do it this way:

```
sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle().getCoreXf();
```

The getCoreXf() method returns:

```
<xml-fragment numFmtId="14" fontId="0" fillId="2" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFill="1" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"/>
```

Sample code (to compare styles of two cells):

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("res/Book1.xlsx"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

CTXf style1 = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle().getCoreXf();
CTXf style2 = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCellStyle().getCoreXf();
System.out.println(style1);
System.out.println(style1.equals(style2)); //true if both are same and false if they are different
```

This seems to be working fine. Please try!